# Why does my superclass call the subclass' method instead of its own in Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, inheritance, uiview

**Here's an example project: http://cl.ly/3N2u2i1S441M**

I'm in a `UITableViewCell` superclass, because when the subclass is being initiated I call `super.init()`. At the bottom of the `init`s for both the subclass and the superclass, I call a method, call `styleCell` that applies styling to it. This method is from a protocol they both conform to, with one implicitly conforming because it's the subclass and it overrides the method.

At the end of the super class' `init`, that style method gets called, but it calls the *subclass'* `styleCell` method, not its own.

Why on earth is this happening?

Is this a bug with Swift? I'm attaching some code in addition to the project above to show the issue:

Superclass table cell:

```
class SuperTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, Style {
    var mysuperview: UIView!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        mysuperview = UIView()

        doStyle()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Must be created in code.")
    }

    func doStyle() {
        print("super class")
    }
}
```

Subclass table cell:

```
class SubTableViewCell: SuperTableViewCell {
    var mysubview: UIView!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        mysubview = UIView()

        doStyle()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Must be created in code.")
    }

    override func doStyle() {
        super.doStyle()

        mysubview!.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }
}
```

Style class and protocol:

```
class StyleManager: NSObject {

}

protocol Style {
    func doStyle()
}
```

This causes a runtime error with the crash occurring when the subclass cell tries to set its view in `doStyle()`.

Comment: can you post code, MCVE?

Comment: What does MCVE mean? I'll try to get code up shortly.

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thought about this a lot and I think the best illustration of what is going on is by putting it all in one "class".

By overriding the `doStyle` function you are effectively replacing it. You can still access it with `super.` but we don't have a way to call `super.`
 from the `super class` and make it point to it's own method. This also makes sense because super and subclasses are not two objects. They are one object with actually one source of code where one piece is in the super and another in the sub.

So when the `doStyle` function gets triggered by the `super init` it sees the replaced/overridden method.

`override` is great at doing what the name says it does, overriding methods. It is almost implied you don't use super.method and override method side by side.

Aside from all that it is also just bad practice. Use unique names for unique functions (which is what you have). In some way it makes sense to use the same name / a protocol because in each function you are setting a style. But these are not two separate classes that both need a style. You are effectively setting a basic style and a specific style. Two different things that both need to be done.

```
class SuperSubIllustation {
    // super and sub class as one for illustation

    init() {
        subInit()
    }


    func superInit() {
        print("super init")

        overrideDoStyle() // this calls the sub style because it's own method is overridden

    }

    func subInit() { // the sub init, this overrides the superInit
       print("sub init")

        superInit() // the super.init()

        overrideDoStyle() // the sub style

    }

    func doStyle() {
        print("super style")
    }

    func overrideDoStyle() {
        print("sub style")

        doStyle() // the super.doStyle

    }
}
```

---

Side Note :

When subclassing you often create increasingly more specific code. For example a series of UIButton classes.

```
class RoundedCornersButton : UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    }
}


class GreenButton : RoundedCornersButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }
}

class RedButton : RoundedCornersButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
```

Even though both `init` and `super.init` are called, there are no conflicts because the subclass does not call both it's own `init` and it's super's `init`.